# Is this possible in Excel? (VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I want to create a VBA macro that will do the following:

The Excel file with the Macro should only open when the file is opened from a certain folder in the Windows directory.

If it is not opened from the specified folder, it needs to show an error msgbox and close the file automatically.

The file we're using is already completely secured however users can still copy it from the existing folder to their desktop for example, we want to prevent them from using an older version by only accepting the opening of the file from a certain directory. I've tried looking around the internet for a solution but did not find it.

---

- Opened from includes shortcuts.
- It is a corportate file but macros are used in our environment.
- I need code where I can edit the folder name to be anything I want
  (so we can always change it later)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. To get the best shot at getting the answer you need can you update your question with the following information please: Where on your system is the file located, what is it called, will this be used in a corporate setting, when you say opened from are you including shortcuts, why do you need this restriction and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also worth pointing out that if this is a corporate file, most business users have macros blocked by default and so the macro won't fire when the book is opened.

Comment: Opened from includes shortcuts.

It is a corportate file but macros are used in our environment.
I need code where I can edit the folder name to be anything I want (so we can always change it later)

The file we're using is already completely secured however users can still copy it from the existing folder to their desktop for example, we want to prevent them from using an older version by only accepting the opening of the file fro ma certain directory.
I've tried looking around the internet for a solution but did not find it.

Comment: This is pretty simple, but it'd be great if you showed some work on what you have so far. Try using a workbook open event and a path variable with an if statement..

Comment: So in effect you're looking for a form of version control. I don't suppose you're busienss is open to the idea of getting SharePoint? :D

Comment: This is pretty simple, but it'd be great if you showed some work on what you have so far. Try using a workbook open event and a path variable with an if statement. - Raystafarian

How would I do this?
Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Place this in **thisworkbook** in the VBA Editor:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Dim strPath As String
strPath = "c:\username\path\to\workbook"

If Not Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path = strPath Then
    MsgBox ("This is an old version, please use the correct version at " & strPath)
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Just change `strPath` to the path you want to use. You might also replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` if you feel the need.

If it's on a network share, be sure to test out what `.path` gives you, as it may replace the network location with a drive letter, which could change across users.